# Nokogiri with error parsing xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri

Why this code always returns zero ?

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><l1><x:Menu xmlns:x="http://www.xworld.org/">OK</Menu></l1></root>')
ret = doc.xpath("//Menu")
ret.size() # return zero
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I have to declare the namespace.

```
doc.xpath("//x:Menu", "x" => "http://www.xworld.org/").text()
```

:)

Comment: btw. I often use css() for simple things ;)